# How to store a python function within an XML file

Tags: python, xml, serialization, import

I'm developing a GUI application in Python that stores it's documents in an XML based format. The application is a mathematical model which several pre-defined components which can be drag-and-dropped. I'd also like the user to be able to create custom components by writing a python function inside an editor provided within the application. My issue is with storing these functions in the XML.

A function might look something like this:

```
def func(node, timestamp):
    return node.weight * timestamp.day + 4
```

These functions are wrapped in an object which provides a standard way of calling them (compared to the pre-defined components). If I was to create one from Python directly it would look like this:

```
parameter = ParameterFunction(func)
```

The function is then called by the model like this:

```
parameter.value(node=node, timestamp=timestamp)
```

The `ParameterFunction` object has a `to_xml` and `from_xml` functions which need to serialise/deserialise the object to/from an XML representation.

**My question is**: how do I store the Python functions in an XML document?

One solution I have thought of so far is to store the function definition as a string, `eval()` or `exec()` it for use but keep the string, then store the string in a CDATA block in the XML. Are there any issues with this that I'm not seeing?

An alternative would be to store all of the Python code in a separate file, and have the XML reference just the function names. This could be nice as it could be edited easily in an external editor. In which case what is the best way to import the code? I am envisiging fighting with the python import path...

I'm aware there are will be security concerns with running untrusted code, but I'm willing to make this tradeoff for the freedom it gives users.

The specific application I'm referring to is on github. I'm happy to provide more information if it's needed, but I've tried to keep it fairly generic here. https://github.com/snorfalorpagus/pywr/blob/120928eaacb9206701ceb9bc91a5d73740db1953/pywr/core.py#L396-L402

Answer (score 1):

Nope, you have the easiest and best solution that I can think of. Just keep them as strings, as long as your not worried about running the untrusted code.

The way I'd deal with external python scripts containing tiny snippets like yours would be to treat them as plain text files and read them in as strings. This avoids all the problems with importing them. Just read them in and call `exec` on them, then the functions will exist in scope.

**EDIT**: I was going to add something on sandboxing python code, but after a bit of [research](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html) it seems this will not be an easy task, it would be easier to sandbox the entire program. Another longer and harder way to restrict the untrusted code would be to create your own tiny interpreter that only did safe operations (i.e mathematical operations, calling existing functions, etc..)